# How to stop xlim updating when subplots share x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])
plt.plot([0,2], [0,1], scalex=False)
```

plotting the second line does not update the axes xlim:
[image]

However, if I create subplots with a shared x-axis, the `scalex` kwarg appears to have no effect:

```
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
for ax in ax_arr.flat:
    ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])
    ax.plot([0,2], [0,1], scalex=False)
```

[image]

Is there another kwarg or setting somewhere that can be used to stop a plotted line affecting the axes xlim in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scalex` affects the autoscaling in the moment the `plot` is created. It will not be stored to take effect in further calls to `autoscale`.

An option is to turn [autoscaling off](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_autoscalex_on.html) in general for all but the first axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax_arr[1].set_autoscalex_on(False)

for ax in ax_arr.flat:
    ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])
    ax.plot([0,2], [0,1], scalex=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer as it does address my specific minimal example above.  As my "real" example involves subplots where the first plot on each axes will not be the same, I include this further answer in case it's of use to anyone else:

```
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax_arr.flat[0].plot([0,1], [0,1])
ax_arr.flat[1].plot([-1,0], [0,1])

for ax in ax_arr.flat:
    ax.set_autoscalex_on(False)
    ax.plot([0,2], [0,1])
```

[image]